# Unexpected output printing a and a++ inline in C

Tags: c

I am running the following type of C code

```
int a = 0;
printf("%d %d" , a , a++);
```

this code is returning me the output

```
1 0
```

As far as I understand a++ would append the value of a after it is read, and since a gets printed first the output should be `0 0` according to me. Where am I going wrong in understanding this?

Comment: This is undefined behavior, the order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified.

Comment: Does that mean that we cannot comment on the output?

Comment: It's evaluating `a++` first and then `a`. So `a` returns the incremented value.

Comment: But any result is possible since it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Exactly.  Try running this: `int foo(void) {printf("Foo\n"; return 1;} int bar(void) {printf("Bar\n"); return 2;} int main() {printf("%i %i\n", foo(), bar()); return 0;}`

Comment: @AshAR Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: You are confusing what parameter gets *printed* first with what parameter gets *evaluated* first.